# ClassNotFoundException if the jar was created in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, reflection, jar, sdk, android-studio

I'm developing SDK which uses 3 libraries that are developed by myself.
I used to work with Eclipse, so I had 4 projects:
1 for the SDK and 3 for the libraries.
Each one of the 3 was marked as a library and as a result a jar files was created inside the bin folder of this project.
In the SDK project I added the jars to the build path and everything worked correctly.

After moving to AndroidStudio I created a new Project with 4 modules:
1 module for the SDK and 3 for each library.
I put inside the build.gradle file of each module a code which create a jar from the class files ( using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874018/generating-jar-file-with-android-studio-and-gradle) ).
Inside the build.gradle of the SDK I put dependency to these jars files, but in runtime I get ClassNotFoundException.

I unzipped the jars and it looks like the class that wasn't found placed in the correct place (same libraries path).
I took the jars and tried to import them in Eclipse but again I got the same error message during runtime. I performed additional test:
Inside the SDK code I tried to use the class, so I declared a variable of the class that throws the exception and there was no compile error and the import was with the same path of the exception.

Note: I tried to load the class using reflection during runtime.

Do you have any idea what is wrong in the process or any better suggestions how to achieve the same behaviour?

Thanks.

Edit:

build.gradle of the 3 libraries:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
    }
   }

   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  }

task libraryOneJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: 'compileDebugJava') {

    from "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug/"
}
```

This is a build.gradle of a test application which uses the SDK and the 3 libraries

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.galvan.mypackage"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile files('libs/sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/library1.jar')
    compile files('libs/library2.jar')
    compile files('libs/library3.jar')
}
```

with the above build.gradle its not working, but it works when changing the dependencies section the be:

```
   dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
                compile project(':sdk')
            compile project(':library1')
            compile project(':library2')
            compile project(':library3')
}
```

Comment: can you show the build.gradle of your SDK?

Comment: @helleye I edited my question to include the structure of each library's gradle file. I use './gradlew libraryOneJar' task to create the jar and I use it later in the SDK

Comment: Out of 4 build.gradle files, I asked for 1, and you gave the other 3, but not the requested one :) At least can you show the `dependencies` part of the forth build.gradle file. As it uses the three jars, it should reference them.

Comment: @helleye sorry for the mistake, updated again.

Comment: `compile files('libs/library1.jar')` will search for library1.jar inside your (test) module's **libs** folder. So one simple way would be to manually copy all three generated jar files into test_module/libs folder and try again.